# C++ Windows Pipe Writefile to a Variable?

Tags: c++, windows, api, pipe

I used the "Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output" tutorial from msdn.
Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

Everything works fine the parent process display it totally correct. But instead of Reading it from the pipe and write it to the Parent STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE I want to read from the pipe and write the output in a variable type.

Here is what I mean:

```
void ReadFromPipe(void) 

// Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT
// and write to the parent process's pipe for STDOUT. 
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{ 
   DWORD dwRead, dwWritten; 
   CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE]; 
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
   HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

   for (;;) 
   { 
      bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
      if( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 ) break; 

      bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf, 
                       dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
      if (! bSuccess ) break; 
   } 
}
```

I managed to get the chBuf after the Writefile function and tried to build a string out of it but it contains duplicates and characters which I dont want to have in my string. So my string contains of a lot more characters than the parent console output.

My workaround is that I save the output to a file and then stream it to a variable but that solution sucks because if you run two instances of my app I have to manage this to dont overwrite each other file and so on it getting more and more complicated that I would like a cleaner solution

Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I managed to get the chBuf after the Writefile function and tried to build a string out of it but it contains duplicates and characters which I dont want to have in my string. So my string contains of a lot more characters than the parent console output.

Most probably, you are building your string disregarding `dwRead` - i.e., you always assume that the full buffer has been read - or something like that. Still, building an `std::string` out of the data you are reading is actually quite simple:

```
std::string ReadFromPipe(void) { 
    std::string ret;
    DWORD dwRead;
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE]; 
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    for (;;) { 
        bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        if( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 ) break; 
        ret.append(chBuf, dwRead);
    }
    return ret;
}
```